# php mssql next row

Tags: php, sql

I need some advice how to get the next value of a row with while loop in php-mssql.

[same articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUwqF.png)

My code:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';


$result = "SELECT article_id, article_name, pic_link, group, price, ean
FROM artic";



$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $result );

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {

echo '<p><img src="'  .$row[2] . '"/></p>
 <div class="stats-container">
                            <span class="product_price">' .$row[4].'</span>
                            <span class="product_name"> ' .$row[1].' </span>
```

I am always getting the same product as you can see on the attached pic.

Comment: That should work unless you are resetting the cursor in the loop later on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't find real problem with the code provided. All "fetch" functions from php are intended to retrieve the next available row:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Maybe you are doing something with $row assignment later ($row = something instead $row == something).

if the entire loop is:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {

  echo '<p><img src="'  .$row[2] . '"/></p>
    <div class="stats-container">
      <span class="product_price">' .$row[4].'</span>
      <span class="product_name"> ' .$row[1].' </span>';
}
```

it should work fine.